# When to use ternary relationship instead of aggregation in RDBMS?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, rdbms

I was wondering when one would represent a relationship between an entity set and a relationship with a ternary relationship?  I understand the benefit of aggregation, but why use it if there is no attribute in the relationship between the entity set and the relationship set? For instance, a grad student (with a student # and name) works on a project (with pid, start date, and end date) and each project that a student works on has a supervising professor. Every project must have only one professor as supervisor.  The supervisor relation has no attribute that is unique yet I have been told that aggregation should be used, but why?

Answer (score 4):

Aggregation is not just in case there is an attribute in the relationship, ternary is more restrictive in some cases, ill explain with an example:

Let's say you have a small database used for scheduling classes in various dates and assign teachers to those classes at those dates, using ternary relationship it would look something like that:

ERD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FQ87.png

```sql
CREATE TABLE teacher
{
  teacher_id int PRIMARY KEY
}

CREATE TABLE class
{
  class_id int PRIMARY KEY
}

CREATE TABLE date
{
  date_id int PRIMARY KEY
}

CREATE TABLE teaching_class_in_date
{
  date_id int,
  class_id int,
  teacher_id,
  constraint teaching_class_in_date_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_id,class_id,teacher_id)
  constraint teacher_FK FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) references teacher (teacher_id)
  constraint class_FK FOREIGN KEY (class_id) references class (class_id)
  constraint date_FK FOREIGN KEY (date_id) references date (date_id)
}
```

This means that when you want to schedule a new class with a teacher you'll need all three records in teacher, class and date beforehand. but what if you want to assign first a class at a certain date but not sure about the teacher yet ?

you have 2 options, one which I usually see in a messy enterprises databases is to create a dummy record in teacher table to allocate to each new class at a certain date if you're not sure about the teacher yet, and it will show in the GUI as "default", or "empty".
Option two, make the teacher_id not part of the primary key and allow null values to the teacher_id foreign key.

Both are bad decisions, the second is worse as it breaks the database third normal form.

To fix this you can use aggregation like this:

ERD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAEXF.png

So now you'll have an extra table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE class_in_date
{
  date_id int,
  class_id int,
  constraint class_in_date_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_id,class_id)
  constraint class_FK FOREIGN KEY (class_id) references class (class_id)
  constraint date_FK FOREIGN KEY (date_id) references date (date_id)
}
```

Now you can assign the two without worrying about the teacher. it all comes down to requirements, If I didn't create the requirement to assign a class at a certain date without a teacher before hand, then a ternary relationship would have been sufficient.

Hope this helped !

Answer (score 1):

Case 1, Binary ownership each project has only one student and one prof (1,1) (Ternary on project)

```
Student(sid,..)
Professor(pid,..)
Project(pid,sid,..)
```

Case 2, Each project has more than one student and one prof, each student has one project. (1,N) (Ternary on project aggregating student)

```
Student(sid,pid,...)
Professor(pid,..)
Project(pid,..)
```

Case 3 each project may have more than one student and each student may have more than one project (N,N) (aggregate)

```
Student(sid,...)
Professor(pid,..)
Project(pid,..)
StudentProject(pid,sud) //One entry for each student working on a project
```

If you've been told to use an aggregate for an entity without an (N,N) relationship, this might be a form of future-proofing.

The difference lies in what table you should store the relationship to project.

Comment: Perhaps to be more clear, I was asking about using a ternary relationship between the professor, works_in, and student. Im a bit confused with your answer

Comment: The ER diagram must be mapped to a relational database, I have specified 3 different table layouts.  The relationship holds even if the relationship does not have any attributes.   Aggregation describes a list of entities in a relationship. If there is only a (1,1) mapping of the relationship, it is pointless to aggregate, because it can be represented as ownership(case 1), if it (1,N) on (A,B) , store the edge in table A, if it is (N,N) create a table for the edge.

Comment: If you've been told to use an aggregate table, that's probably because they expect the relationship may become (N,N0 in the future.