# Difference between a ternary relationship and an aggregation in er modelling?

Tags: entity-relationship

How to recognize if a relationship is ternary or an aggregation?

For example: A player gets an award in a match he plays. If the entities are player, match and award, is this a ternary or an aggregation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use ternary relationship instead of aggregation in RDBMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381446/when-to-use-ternary-relationship-instead-of-aggregation-in-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given to me by a lecturer, it's a ternary relationship because there are 3 contributing entities involved.

[image]

Aggregation is, on the other hand, where you aggregate two entities into a single entity and create another relationship to support m:m scenarios. Kind of like a possibility for a relationship to participate in another relationship. For example;

**Courses are offered during a semester. Some course offerings may have exams in it.**
[image]